# Javascript add items to object data: {}

Tags: javascript, object, axios

I wonder how I can add items to my data object.

This is how I make a post request using axios:

```
axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'someUrl',
    responseType: 'json',
    data: {
        title: titleData
    }
})
```

But sometimes I need to add more items to the data object depending on how many fields the user has filled.

So sometimes the request data might look like this:

```
axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'someUrl',
    responseType: 'json',
    data: {
        title: titleData,
        location: locationData,
        isReady: readyData
    }
})
```

So how can I push items to the `data: {}` object?

Comment: `var data = {}; if (...) data.foo = 'bar';`…?! – No need to be unnecessarily clever here.

Comment: So use an object and add items to it and reference the object...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you add property directly by their name

`data['newPropertyName'] = value`

or

`data.newPropertyName = value`

Answer (score 2):

With axios, the field data must contain an object, so :

```
var data = { title:titleData };

if (mySpecialCase)
{
    data["location"] = locationData;
    data["isReady"] = isReady;
}

axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'someUrl',
    responseType: 'json',
    data: data
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could keep the object in a variable, then pass on request:

```
var data={};
//then assign
data.title="test";
//or multiple at once
Object.assign(data, {
        location: locationData,
        isReady: readyData
});
//then do the request
axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: 'someUrl',
      responseType: 'json',
      data
    })
```